# Create individual files from 1 CSV

Tags: mysql, r, csv, text-files, data-manipulation

I'm extracting data from a MySQL database creating a CSV file with two columns: ID and Text. I would like to know an easy way (SQL, text editor or R solutions) to create a text file for each row containing the second column (text format) with the ID from the first column as the name of the text file. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R I would do the following:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
   write.table(df$Text[i], 
               file = paste0(df$ID[i], ".txt"), 
               col.names = F, row.names = F)
}

list.files()
# [1] "1.txt"  "10.txt" "11.txt" "12.txt" "13.txt" "14.txt" "15.txt" "16.txt"  
# ----
# "76.txt" "77.txt" "78.txt" "79.txt" "8.txt" "80.txt" "81.txt" "82.txt" "9.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a loop based on what you said @Ken S. but it's 90,000 rows that need to be converted into individual files. The R loop is only able to produce 5 per minute, which means it would take several days to finish. Thanks though!

```
for (i in 1:91020) {number=descriptions[i,1]
text=descriptions[i,2]
print(text)
write.table(text,file=paste0(number, ".txt"))}
```